# CPU Overloading due to some hooks

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, cpu-usage

I have some functions restricted in some hooks. The purpose of these hooks was to have consistent author name in the DB(which is a product attribute) and also update the display name. I placed this in functions.php and created hooks for these functions which I thought of implementing/triggering these hooks through WP-Crontrol plugin, apparently these functions were causing CPU Overloading (when checked in AWS instance). And I'm confused why the CPU is overloading due to these hooks?

```
function replace_authors_name_attributes()
{

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $products = new WP_Query($args);


    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();
            $product_id = get_the_ID();
            echo "Product ID: " . $product_id . "\n";


            $product_attributes = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', true);


            if (!empty($product_attributes)) {
                $attributes = maybe_unserialize($product_attributes);

                if (is_array($attributes) && isset($attributes['authors_name']) && isset($attributes['authors_name']['value'])) {
                    $authors_name = $attributes['authors_name']['value'];
                    echo "Author's Name: " . $authors_name . "\n<br>";


                    if ($authors_name === 'Ram' || $authors_name === 'Ramu') {
                        $new_author_name = 'Ram Rao';
                        echo "Replacing with: " . $new_author_name . "\n<br>";


                        $attributes['authors_name']['value'] = $new_author_name;
                        update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes);
                        echo "Attribute updated.\n<br>";
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
function schedule_authors_consistency() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('consistent_author')) {
        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'consistent_author');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'schedule_authors_consistency');

add_action('consistent_author', 'replace_authors_name_attributes');


function update_user_display_name($user_id, $new_display_name)
{
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->users,
        array('display_name' => $new_display_name),
        array('ID' => $user_id),
        array('%s'),
        array('%d')
    );
}
function update_authors_display_name() {

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);

if ($products->have_posts()) {
    while ($products->have_posts()) {
        $products->the_post();
        $product_id = get_the_ID();
        echo "Product ID: " . $product_id . "\n";


        $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $product_id);

        if ($author_id) {
            $current_display_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
            echo "Current Display Name: " . $current_display_name . "\n<br>";

            if ($current_display_name === 'Ram') {
                $new_display_name = 'Ram Rao';
                echo "Replacing with: " . $new_display_name . "\n<br>";

                update_user_display_name($author_id, $new_display_name);
                echo "Display Name updated.\n<br>";
            }
        
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No products found.\n";
}
}

wp_reset_postdata();
function schedule_authors_display_name_assignment() {

    if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_authors_display_name_event')) {

        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'update_authors_display_name_event');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'schedule_authors_display_name_assignment');

add_action('update_authors_display_name_event', 'update_authors_display_name');



function get_user_id_from_authors_name($authors_name)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->users WHERE display_name = %s", $authors_name)
    );
    return $user_id;
}

function update_post_authors() {


$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$products = new WP_Query($args);


if ($products->have_posts()) {
    while ($products->have_posts()) {
        $products->the_post();
        $product_id = get_the_ID();
        echo "Product ID: " . $product_id . "\n";


        $product_attributes = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', true);


        if (!empty($product_attributes)) {
            $attributes = maybe_unserialize($product_attributes);

            if (is_array($attributes) && isset($attributes['authors_name']) && isset($attributes['authors_name']['value'])) {
                $authors_name = $attributes['authors_name']['value'];
                echo "Author's Name: " . $authors_name . "\n<br>";


                $user_id = get_user_id_from_authors_name($authors_name);

                if ($user_id) {
                    echo "User ID: " . $user_id . "\n<br>";


                    wp_update_post(array('ID' => $product_id, 'post_author' => $user_id));
                    echo "Post Author updated.\n<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "User ID not found for the given author's name.\n<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No products found.\n";
}
}
wp_reset_postdata();

function schedule_update_post_authors_event() {

    if (!wp_next_scheduled('update_post_authors_event')) {

        wp_schedule_single_event(time(), 'update_post_authors_event');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'schedule_update_post_authors_event');

add_action('update_post_authors_event', 'update_post_authors');
```

I know that the function which updates the display_name is a mistake, instead of iterating through all the products, I should have just updated the wp_users table.

These hooks were not triggered or executed from wp-crontrol. Why is the CPU overloading? If I know the possible reason. I may prevent this from happening in the future. please do shoot me any error in my question!!
Thanks

Comment: These hooks weren't even executed and CPU is overloading by their presence. Not sure why its happening?